# Ideal hardware requirements for ANDROID DEVELOPMENT

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need information about minimum or ideal hardware requirement for better experience in developing Android application. I am using Android Studio in developing an application.

My current hardware specifications is:

```
CPU - Intel Core i5-4460 CPU @ 3.20GHz 3.20GHz,
RAM - 8Gb,
System type - 64 bit OS, x64-based processor
```

But still I am experiencing sluggish operation, this is my studio64.exe content,

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.2
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

for the configuration of heap size in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Most critical parts are disk and ram:

1. Minimum 16gb of RAM if You will use Emulator + Google Chrome.
2. SSD for faster build times.

Of course, CPU and GPU should be powerful too. My GTX 760 and i7 3770 load percents always keeping lower than 100. So Your i5 4th gen. CPU should be enough.

Comment: why need good GPU for Android developing?

Answer (score 0):

These are the Official minimum system requirement for running Android Studio in a Windows machine.

> 1. Microsoft® Windows® 8/7/Vista/2003 (32 or 64-bit)
> 2. 2 GB RAM minimum, 4 GB RAM recommended
> 3. 400 MB hard disk space At least 1 GB for Android
>      SDK,
> 4. emulator system images, and caches 1280 x 800 minimum screen
>      resolution
> 5. Java Development Kit (JDK) 7
> 6. Optional for accelerated
>      emulator: Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T
>      (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality

Note: The sluggish operation you are facing is because of the heavy use of system by Android Studio, otherwise your system is sufficient enough from the standard requirement.  Right now we can hope for a better memory optimized Android Studio from Google in the next releases.